# Most efficient way to search how many times a number appears in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for an efficient way to find how many times a particular number appears in a sorted array.

My current code:

```
public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,4,7,7,7,7,7,8};
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
            if (x[i] == 7) ++count;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array x is not sorted. You can use binary search to find the count of a number.

Comment: Sure.  Binary search for n-1, binary search for n+1, find the number of elements in between.

Comment: Your approach gives you O(n) while the binary approach does it in O(logn)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, O (2 lg n) ? (plus some constant)

Comment: O(2 lg n) is the same as O(lg n).  Constants don't count.

Comment: forgot to sort the array in the site (edited)

Comment: Correct, multiplied constants are irrelevent, as well as the constants

Comment: You are not searching, you are counting. You must look at every element to count, therefore O(N) is the most efficient you can get. You also are not guaranteed consecutive numbers, so I don't think the binary search difference solution can work that way

Comment: More related to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: as cricket said 
if im going to use binary search i wont be able to count how many times a number appears..

Comment: You need to find an index of first occurrence, then an index of the last occurrence, and the difference of the indexes gives you result.

Comment: In c++ you would use upper_bound on n - 1 and lower_bound on n + 1. So two binary searches. In the second search you use the discovered index as the left bracket. You need to take care of the case where the elements with the closest values to the one you want are themselves duplicated. Ironically the equivalent functions don't exist in the simply gigantic Java library (which seems to only consist of a terrible date library and kludges for generics). In Java you can pick the right hand one off quite simply but the left hand one is not so trivial.

Comment: If you have atleast Java 7, you've got `Array.binarySearch`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the array is sorted, as mentioned in the comments, you can perform 2 binary searches to find the lowest index in the array where the number appears and the highest index where the number appears. Add in a binary search to find *some* index, and you get an O(log n) algorithm.

Try this code out with some different array values.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int numberToCount = 7;

    final int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,4,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8};

    final int indexOfKnownOccurence = Arrays.binarySearch(x, numberToCount);
    if (indexOfKnownOccurence < 0) {
        System.out.println("No instances of the number found");
        return;
    }

    final int lowerBound = findIndexOfFirstOccurence(x, numberToCount, 0, indexOfKnownOccurence);

    final int upperBound = findIndexOfLastOccurence(x, numberToCount, indexOfKnownOccurence, x.length - 1);

    System.out.println("Lower bound: " + lowerBound);
    System.out.println("Upper bound: " + upperBound);
    System.out.println("Number of occurrences: " + (upperBound - lowerBound + 1));
}

//Binary search for start index
public static int findIndexOfFirstOccurence(final int[] x, final int numberToFind, final int startIndex, final int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return startIndex;
    } else if (x[startIndex] == numberToFind) {
        return startIndex;
    } else if (startIndex + 1 == endIndex) {
        return endIndex;
    }

    final int midIndex = startIndex + (int)Math.floor((endIndex - startIndex) / 2);

    if (x[midIndex] == numberToFind) {
        return findIndexOfFirstOccurence(x, numberToFind, startIndex, midIndex);
    } else {
        return findIndexOfFirstOccurence(x, numberToFind, midIndex, endIndex);
    }
}

//Binary search for end index
public static int findIndexOfLastOccurence(final int[] x, final int numberToFind, final int startIndex, final int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return endIndex;
    } else if (x[endIndex] == numberToFind) {
        return endIndex;
    } else if (startIndex + 1 == endIndex) {
        return startIndex;
    }

    final int midIndex = startIndex + (int)Math.floor((endIndex - startIndex) / 2);

    if (x[midIndex] == numberToFind) {
        return findIndexOfLastOccurence(x, numberToFind, midIndex, endIndex);
    } else {
        return findIndexOfLastOccurence(x, numberToFind, startIndex, midIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really what they meant either! ;) However it is an improvement on my suggestion as you reduce the number of comparisons (potentially), whether this segmented binary search is worth the effort over a linear scan should be determined really by profiling...

Comment: I must have misunderstood what the others were saying in the comments. But I do think this is optimal (from a worst-case theoretical standpoint). For large lists, it would be better, but it is hard to say for small lists.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on how long your array is, if it's only few 10s of elements, it's probably more efficient to do a linear scan. If it's a larger array, I'd recommend using `Array.binarySearch()` as in the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,4,7,7,7,7,7,8};
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(x, 7);
    System.out.println(index);
    int count = 0;
    if (index >= 0) {
        // search down
        int i = index - 1;
        for (; i >= 0 && x[i] == 7; --i) {
        }
        // search up
        for (++index; index < x.length && x[index] == 7; ++index) {
        }
        count = index - (i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Firstly binary search will tell you if this item is present in the array, if it is, you don't really know where in the range the search found the element, but you have to do a linear scan in both directions to determine the exact count, however the number of comparisons you have to do is at most the count of this particular key... (excluding the binary search)

Comment: That's not what others meant when they suggested using a binary search.

Comment: @Chill - yes I know, but the other suggestions will not work as it's a *counting* problem..

Comment: I've added a solution that does not use counting. It takes advantage of the fact that the array is sorted.